# Calculate the middle of two unit length 3D vectors without a square root?

Tags: math, vector, 3d, trigonometry

With two 3D, unit length vectors, is there a way to calculate a unit length vector in-between these, without re-normalizing? (more specifically without a square root).

Currently I'm just adding them both and normalizing, but for efficiency I thought there might be some better way.

---

*(for the purpose of this question, ignore the case when both vectors are directly opposite)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an answer to the original question; I am rather trying to resolve the issues between two answers and it wouldn't fit into a comment.

- The [trigonometric approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23228994/341970) is 4x slower than your original version with the square-root function on *my* machine (Linux, Intel Core i5). Your mileage will vary.
- The `asm ("");` is always a bad smell with his siblings `volatile` and `(void) x`.
- Running a tight loop many-many times is a very unreliable way of benchmarking.

What to do instead?

1. Analyze the generated assembly code to see what the compiler actually did to your source code.
2. Use a profiler. I can recommend `perf` or `Intel VTune`.

---

If you look at the assembly code of [your micro-benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23243080/341970), you will see that the compiler is very smart and figured out that v1 and v2 are not changing and eliminated as much work as it could at compile time. At runtime, no calls were made to `sqrtf` or to `acosf` and `cosf`. That explains why you did not see any difference between the two approaches.

---

Here is an edited version of your benchmark. I scrambled it a bit and guarded against division by zero with `1.0e-6f`. (It doesn't change the conclusions.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#ifdef USE_NORMALIZE
#warning "Using normalize"

void mid_v3_v3v3_slerp(float res[3], const float v1[3], const float v2[3])
{
    float m;

    float v[3] = { (v1[0] + v2[0]), (v1[1] + v2[1]), (v1[2] + v2[2]) };

    m = 1.0f / sqrtf(v[0] * v[0] + v[1] * v[1] + v[2] * v[2] + 1.0e-6f);

    v[0] *= m;
    v[1] *= m;
    v[2] *= m;

    res[0] = v[0];
    res[1] = v[1];
    res[2] = v[2];
}
#else
#warning "Not using normalize"

void mid_v3_v3v3_slerp(float v[3], const float v1[3], const float v2[3])
{
    const float dot_product = v1[0] * v2[0] + v1[1] * v2[1] + v1[2] * v2[2];
    const float theta = acosf(dot_product);
    const float n = 1.0f / (2.0f * cosf(theta * 0.5f) + 1.0e-6f);

    v[0] = (v1[0] + v2[0]) * n;
    v[1] = (v1[1] + v2[1]) * n;
    v[2] = (v1[2] + v2[2]) * n;
}
#endif

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long long int i = 20000000;
    float v1[3] = {-0.8659117221832275, 0.4995948076248169, 0.024538060650229454};
    float v2[3] = {0.7000154256820679, 0.7031427621841431, -0.12477479875087738};
    float v[3] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };

    while (--i) {
        mid_v3_v3v3_slerp( v, v1, v2);
        mid_v3_v3v3_slerp(v1,  v, v2);
        mid_v3_v3v3_slerp(v1, v2, v );  
    }

    printf("done %f %f %f\n", v[0], v[1], v[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with `gcc -ggdb3 -O3 -Wall -Wextra -fwhole-program -DUSE_NORMALIZE -march=native -static normal.c -lm` and profiled the code with `perf`.

The trigonometric approach is 4x slower and it is because the expensive `cosf` and `acosf` functions.

I have tested the Intel C++ Compiler as well: `icc -Ofast -Wall -Wextra -ip -xHost normal.c`; the conclusion is the same, although gcc generates approximately 10% slower code (for `-Ofast` as well).

I wouldn't even try to implement an approximate `sqrtf`: It is already an intrinsic and chances are, your approximation will only be slower...

---

Having said all these, I don't know the answer to the original question. I thought about it and I also suspect that the there might be another way that doesn't involve the square-root function.

Interesting question in theory; in practice, I doubt that getting rid of that square-root would make any difference in speed in your application.

Comment: Bench-marked on GCC4.9, AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1055T, And using `sqrtf` is a little over 3x faster.

Comment: @ideasman42 As I wrote: *"Your mileage will vary."* But the conclusion is still the same: The `sqrtf` version is significantly faster than the trigonometric approach.

Answer (score 1):

First, find the angle between your two vectors. From the principle of [scalar projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_projection), we know that

```
|a| * cos(theta) = a . b_hat
```

`.` being the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) operator, `|a|` being the length of `a`, `theta` being the angle between `a` and `b`, and `b_hat` being the normalized form of `b`.
In your situation, a and b are already unit vectors, so this simplifies to:

```
cos(theta) = a . b
```

which we can rearrange to:

```
theta = acos(a . b)
```

Lay vectors A and B end to end, and complete the triangle by drawing a line from the start of the first vector to the end of the second. Since two sides are of equal length, we know the triangle is isoceles, so it's easy to determine all of the angles if you already know theta.

[image]

That line with length N is the middle vector. We can normalize it if we divide it by N.

From the [law of sines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines), we know that

```
sin(theta/2)/1 = sin(180-theta)/N
```

Which we can rearrange to get

```
N = sin(180-theta) / sin(theta/2)
```

Note that you'll divide by zero when calculating N if A and B are equal, so it may be useful to check for that corner case before starting.

---

Summary:

```
dot_product = a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y + a.z * b.z
theta = acos(dot_product)
N = sin(180-theta) / sin(theta/2)
middle_vector = [(a.x + b.x) / N, (a.y + b.y) / N, (a.z + b.z) / N]
```

Comment: For additional efficiency, I think N can also be calculated as `2 * cos(theta/2)` if you use the [double angle formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html), although I haven't rigorously proven it. The graphs look pretty similar on [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28pi-x%29%2Fsin%28x%2F2%29+vs+2*cos%28x%2F2%29), at least. Incidentally, this removes the divide-by-zero issue when A == B.

Comment: I am not sure that there is a gain in performance when you calculate trigonometrical functions instead of square roots. There is a well established fast algorithm to calculate the inverse of a square root (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root).

Comment: @rpsml, fast inverse square root is more an approximation, its fine in some cases but not really a stable solution generally.

Comment: @ideasman42, indeed, performance comes with a price. My point is that replacing a square root by trigonometric functions will probably not lead to performance improvement. If you want to process faster, you have to give up somewhere. Incidentally, the accuracy of a fast inverse sqrt is amazingly good for most graphical applications.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers I made some speed comparison.

*Edit*. with this nieve benchmark, GCC optimizes out the trigonometry yeilding approx the same speeds for both methods, Read @Ali's post for a more complete explanation.

In summery, using re-normalizing is approx 4x faster.

```or-tag-here
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

/* gcc mid_v3_v3v3_slerp.c -lm -O3 -o mid_v3_v3v3_slerp_a
 * gcc mid_v3_v3v3_slerp.c -lm -O3 -o mid_v3_v3v3_slerp_b -DUSE_NORMALIZE
 *
 * time ./mid_v3_v3v3_slerp_a
 * time ./mid_v3_v3v3_slerp_b
 */

#ifdef USE_NORMALIZE
#warning "Using normalize"

void mid_v3_v3v3_slerp(float v[3], const float v1[3], const float v2[3])
{
    float m;

    v[0] = (v1[0] + v2[0]);
    v[1] = (v1[1] + v2[1]);
    v[2] = (v1[2] + v2[2]);

    m = 1.0f / sqrtf(v[0] * v[0] + v[1] * v[1] + v[2] * v[2]);

    v[0] *= m;
    v[1] *= m;
    v[2] *= m;
}
#else
#warning "Not using normalize"

void mid_v3_v3v3_slerp(float v[3], const float v1[3], const float v2[3])
{
    const float dot_product = v1[0] * v2[0] + v1[1] * v2[1] + v1[2] * v2[2];
    const float theta = acosf(dot_product);
    const float n = 1.0f / (2.0f * cosf(theta * 0.5f));

    v[0] = (v1[0] + v2[0]) * n;
    v[1] = (v1[1] + v2[1]) * n;
    v[2] = (v1[2] + v2[2]) * n;
}
#endif

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long long int i = 10000000000;
    const float v1[3] = {-0.8659117221832275, 0.4995948076248169, 0.024538060650229454};
    const float v2[3] = {0.7000154256820679, 0.7031427621841431, -0.12477479875087738};
    float v[3];

    while (--i) {
        asm (""); /* prevent compiler from optimizing the loop away */
        mid_v3_v3v3_slerp(v, v1, v2);
    }

    printf("done %f %f %f\n", v[0], v[1], v[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not very surprised. Most implementations of trigonometric and sqrt are based on Taylor series. Trigonometric functions have a slight advantage that any value can be reduced to half a quadrant. For the sqrt you can look at this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/69941/Best-Square-Root-Method-Algorithm-Function-Precisi . I would be curious on whether your code run faster with either the fast inverse sqrt or one of the fastest methods in the above link.

Comment: And I would check the assembly code. Maybe the compiler couldn't throw away the entire loop but could throw away the actual computations and basically do just one iteration and then only countdown in the loop. In theory, it is possible; in practice, you would have to check the assembly code to see what happened.

Comment: @Ali, the difference with/without `asm ("");` was huge, many 100s of times slower, it seems logical it runs the function each time.

Comment: @ideasman42 Look at the assembly and you will understand why. The compiler is smarter than you think it is, and did something very clever to render the benchmark moot. I will soon post an answer explaining it. In the meantime: it did what I had expected, eliminated the work.